# What "cup" is Genie referring to?

Tags: aladdin-2019

In *Aladdin* (2019), Genie says to Aladdin:

> Genie: Don't ever interrupt me, no matter what. Now, I usually don't
>   have to go through all of this... because by the time the guy gets to
>   me, he pretty much knows what he wants...and it generally has to do
>   with tons of money and power! Do me a favor, do not drink from **that
>   cup**. I promise you there is not enough money and power on earth for
>   you to be satisfied.

What "cup" is Genie referring to?

Comment: **"Don't be *that guy*"**

Comment: Might also be a Holy Grail reference, but it's too vague compared to most of Genie's other references.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a metaphor¹. The 'cup'<sub><sup><sup><sup>2</sup></sup></sup></sub> represents asking for money and power which is what most everyone in the past has done in this situation; i.e. *being owed a wish from a genie*.

'Drinking from that cup' would be analogous to doing what most everyone has done in the past.

He's saying *'Everyone asks for money and power. Don't ask for money and power because no matter how much I give you, you won't be satisfied.'*

The subtext to that dialogue is that Genie has played out that scenario multiple times and he's sick and tired of watching his 'master' self-destruct as history repeats itself. [Those who cannot remember the past are condemned to repeat it](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/those-who-cannot-remember-the-past-are-condemned-to-repeat-it). He's warning Aladdin against making the same mistake as previous 'masters'.

---

¹ <sub>[Metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor) - A metaphor is a figure of speech that, for rhetorical effect, directly refers to one thing by mentioning another. It may provide clarity or identify hidden similarities between two ideas.</sub>

<sup><sup><sup>2</sup></sup></sup> <sub>'Drinking from cups' has been used as a metaphor since (and may indeed originate from) [The Bible](https://biblia.com/bible/kjv1900/1%20Cor%2010.21)</sub>

Comment: I'd think an even better Bible quote would be Jesus' "Let this cup pass from me"/"Take away this cup from me" ([Matthew 26:39](https://biblehub.com/kjv/matthew/26.htm#31), Mark 14:36, Luke 22:42). In that context, the cup holds your fate — drink from the cup, swallow what's in it, and you irreversibly accept it. It connotes an action which cannot be undone.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I think this should be an answer. It's a very good reference and explanation.

Answer (score -2):

It is a metaphor, but it's also more than that. At the time the arabian nights was written, a cup would likely have contained wine, which intoxicates, or poison, which kills (indeed, I believe the original Alaeddin story involved a poisoned / drugged chalice)

So with the phrase "do not drink from THAT cup" he in some small way captures both the uses of a cup; that power and wealth intoxicate and that, ultimately, they lead only to an untimely death.

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if you could find the original quote from Aladdin that supports the drugged/poisoned chalice theory.